Polysynth in p5 error: oldestNote not defined
I was trying to use polysynth in p5 in a for loop to play the notes in the array one after the other, but I kept getting that error (ReferenceError: oldestNote is not defined), as well as all the notes in the array sounding at once:
let polySynth;
let notes = ['C3', 'G3', 'D4', 'A4', 'E5', 'Bb5', 'Gb5', 'Db4', 'Ab4', 'Eb3', 'Bb3', 'F2']

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  polySynth = new p5.PolySynth();
}

function draw() {
  playSynth()
}

function playSynth() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    note = notes[i]
    userStartAudio();
    let velocity = 10;
    let time = 0;
    let dur = 1;
    polySynth.play(note, velocity, time, dur);
  }
}

If anyone can help me figure out why this error is happening, that would be greatly appreciated

The for loop is synchronous, so there is no delay between iterations. That's why the notes are all playing at once. Also, won't putting the playSynth function inside draw have it repeating 45x per second? There should probably be a let before the note variable inside your loop, as well.

I'm not sure about the oldestNote error: I don't see any variable named that in the code you've included?

Can you share the full stack trace? Is oldestNote an internal error or pointing to your code? If your code, then this doesn't reproduce it.

Try this. I cobbled that up from the example on this page. Note the differences - the variables have been moved from the loop, and the time is incremented by a third, and that seems to have fixed it. Also, draw() isn't used, since it seems to produce a bubbling / gargling effect.
